# from nltk.util import Trie ImportError: cannot import name Trie

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

I am new in `NLP (Natural Language Processing)`, I have installed `NLTK` on my computer and I have downloaded all the packages using `nltk.download()`

> My Script

```
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize

example_text = "Hello Mr. Shan, how are you doing? the weather is quite cool today in Guwahati. I heard you are going to Delhi tomorrow."

print(sent_tokenize(example_text))
```

> Error

```
C:\wamp64\www\python\NLTK>python test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 1, in <module>
    from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\__init__.py", line 129, in <module>
    from nltk.collocations import *
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\collocations.py", line 38, in <module
>
    from nltk.util import ngrams
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\util.py", line 10, in <module>
    import inspect
  File "C:\Python27\lib\inspect.py", line 39, in <module>
    import tokenize
  File "C:\wamp64\www\python\NLTK\tokenize.py", line 1, in <module>
    """Tokenization help for Python programs.
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\tokenize\__init__.py", line 67, in <m
odule>
    from nltk.tokenize.mwe import MWETokenizer
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\tokenize\mwe.py", line 31, in <module
>
    from nltk.util import Trie
ImportError: cannot import name Trie
```

Answer (score 2):

I can see that your script is named test.py, but I'm wondering if at any point you created a tokenize.py file? Try removing any tokenize.pyc and renaming any tokenize.py file. I had this same issue just now. Upon renaming the file it worked.

Also note that you will have to import nltk before being able to call from nltk.

Reference:
[cannot import name defaultdict error for nltk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48352048/cannot-import-name-defaultdict-error-for-nltk)